# How can I get different data with case?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, switch-statement, case

In view If lokasyonno= 27 , I want the first block to run, if not the second block. How can I do it?

I tried to do it with the switch case structure, but I couldn't get a result because there is no common column.

FIRST

```
SELECT round(UH.NETTUTAR)
       FROM TBL_IRSALIYE IR
            INNER JOIN TBL_URUNHAREKETLERI UH ON UH.IRSALIYEID = IR.IRSALIYEID
            INNER JOIN TBL_URUNLER U ON UH.URUNID = U.URUNID
      WHERE     IR.LOKASYONNO = 27
            AND IR.TUR = 7
            AND IR.IPTAL = 0
            AND IR.ONAY = 1
            AND IR.BILLED = 1
            AND IR.INTERNET = 60
            AND ROWNUM <= 10
            AND IR.TARIH > TO_DATE ('2020-09-27 ', 'yyyy-mm-dd ')
            AND IR.TARIH <= TO_DATE ('2020-10-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd ')
```

second

```
     NVL (
                             (SELECT ROUND (
                                        SUM (
                                           CASE DOCUMENT_TYPE
                                              WHEN 2
                                              THEN
                                                 (CASE TRANSACTION_TYPE
                                                     WHEN 0
                                                     THEN
                                                          0
                                                        - (  LINE_TOTAL_VALUE
                                                           - LINE_TOTL_DISCOUNT)
                                                     ELSE
                                                          LINE_TOTAL_VALUE
                                                        - LINE_TOTL_DISCOUNT
                                                  END)
                                              ELSE
                                                 (CASE TRANSACTION_TYPE
                                                     WHEN 1
                                                     THEN
                                                          0
                                                        - (  LINE_TOTAL_VALUE
                                                           - LINE_TOTL_DISCOUNT)
                                                     ELSE
                                                        (  LINE_TOTAL_VALUE
                                                         - LINE_TOTL_DISCOUNT)
                                                  END)
                                           END),
                                        10)
                                FROM TBL_TRANSACTION_LINES
                               WHERE     (TRANSACTION_TYPE NOT IN (10, 30))
                                     AND STORE_NO = LOK.LOKASYONNO
                                     AND (URUNID = TBL_URUNLER.URUNID)
                                     AND TRANSACTION_DATE >
                                            TO_DATE ('2020-09-27 0:0:0',
                                                     'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
                                     AND TRANSACTION_DATE <=
                                            TO_DATE ('2020-10-04 0:0:0',
                                                     'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')),
                             0)
                             AS HAFTALIKKASASATISTUTARI
```

Comment: Please reduce the queries to simple versions having the minimum possible to demonstrate the problem - all those joins etc are irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `union` of the two queries but add a `not exists()` on the first query as an additional condition of the second query:

```
<first query>
union all
<second query>
where not exists (<first query>)
```

Comment: its complicated. i couldnt solved the problem. where not exist( full code block)?

Comment: Its giving Subquery returns more than one row error

Comment: @crashed this syntax cannot cause that error. That error must be *within* either the first or second query. If you can run each one independently, then this approach will work; `not exists(...)` is designed to work with queries that return multiple rows